# 'thread' is not a member of 'std' in GCC 4.8

Tags: c++, c++11, stdthread

I'm trying out some c++11 threading support for my current project but facing bottleneck. I use the gcc 4.8.0 built by rubenvb (downloaded directly from sourceforge) [x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.8.0-win64_rubenvb] and find it seems not support c++11 threading features. The following code fails to compile and complains `'thread' is not a member of 'std'`. With googling, there is a 4.7-experimental built (also by rubenvb) with std thread support. As part of my main project requires other C++11 features at 4.8 version, I haven't try out the 4.7 version. Please help to clarify if the toolchain I downloaded is thread-enabled or not.

**Platform**:  Window x64, Qt 4.8 (built from source using the gcc tool-chain downloaded)

- As the Qt libaries are built from source, changing the tool-chains would mean recompile the whole library set, which sound bad to me. Are there anything missed in both files or gcc? Thanks.

*Update*: Just downloaded the experimental 4.8 version [x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.8-stdthread-win64_rubenvb] and the test code compiled. So the question now is

"Does the 'experimental' version safe to use?"

**Test code used**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex> // try other c++11 threading feature

void doSomeWork( void ) { std::cout << "hello from thread..." << std::endl; }
int main() {
    std::mutex m; // also fail here
    std::thread t( doSomeWork );
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

and **makefile used**

```
CC       := g++
SRC      := test$(BUILD).cpp
OBJ      := $(SRC:.cpp=.o)
BIN      := test$(BUILD).exe
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++0x -Wall -Wextra -O0 -ggdb -lpthread -mthreads -pthread -Wno-unknown-pragmas

clean  :        ; del /a/s $(BIN) $(OBJ)
all    : $(BIN) ; del $(OBJ)
$(BIN) : $(OBJ) ; $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@
%.o    : %.cpp  ; $(CC) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
.PHONY: clean all
```

Comment: Can you try from the command line? `g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -Wextra -O0 -ggdb -lpthread -mthreads -pthread -Wno-unknown-pragmas test${BUILD}.cpp`?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the Mingw-Builds have two different threading models, if you're using the win32 one:

> Mingw-Builds (**and the experimental rubenvb packages**) also let you
>   choose between the threading model internally used by (lib)gcc:
>
> posix (built upon MinGW-w64’s winpthreads) “an implementation of POSIX
>   threads for win32 is also available under the experimental directory.
>
> - Its main goal is to support C++11 standard threading, which supports
>     only using POSIX threads at the moment.”
>     http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/
> - enables C++11 library features
>     contained in the headers thread, mutex, and future.
> - Performance
>     degradation in specific scenarios. C++11 functionality is
>     significantly slower than native Win32 implementation or even
>     MSVS2012’s implementation.
>
> win32 uses native Win32 threading
>   functions.
>
> - **no C++11 thread, mutex, or future**
> - best performance

Source: http://qt-project.org/wiki/MinGW-64-bit

Comment: Thx for reply, but the test code I wrote is just a plain C++, no qt-related code and it just fails

Comment: It doesn't have to use Qt. The above link doesn't cite Qt but just the rubenvb package